# Can't center img over background-image (parallax)

Tags: html, css, parallax

Im trying to center a profile picture-like image over my parallax background img, but it is staying in the top left corner of the background img. I want to get it in the center

```css
.natecontain {
  text-align: center;
}

.ohwow {
  width: 30%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/1500x1000");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 60%;
  max-height: 60%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="natecontain">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Oh Wow (Owen Wilson Voice) Its Nate" title="Look at this doooood." class="ohwow" />
</div>
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Comment: when it comes to asking for help, please change your image src values to some online image links so that those images and can be tested as per required.

Answer (score 0):

your image with class 'ohwow' has `position:absolute`. `margin: 0 auto;` will not work with absolute positioned element. So please remove `position:absolute` and i hope it will work.

second option with position: absolute. 
Apply left and top offsets 50%. and add margin-top: "-half height of image" and margin-left: "-half width of image". for example if the image size is 200w X 100h, then the margin can be margin: -50px 0 0 -100px;

try below code

```css
.natecontain
{
text-align: center;

}

.ohwow
{
background-color: red;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin: -50px 0 0 -100px;
}

.parallax {
/* The image used */
background-image: url("nban.jpg");

/* Set a specific height */
min-height: 60%; 
max-height: 60%;

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;




}
```

```html
<div class="natecontain">



        <img src="me.jpg" alt="Oh Wow (Owen Wilson Voice) Its Nate" title="Look at this doooood." class="ohwow"/>

 </div>   
    <div class="parallax"></div>
```

Comment: nah, that just makes the img go above the background, I want it over it, hence the position absolute thing.

Comment: @ConfusedCodeCat. have updated the answer. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Tried it.. not quite. its offset and doesnt scale well

Comment: I have implemented it in your code itself. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

please use
`background-position: center center;` instead of `background-position: center;` also add some content in your container so that some result can be seen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `center` align any *absolutely positioned* element you whould be offsetting its position using `left` and `right` properties (for **horizontal alignment**) and `top` and `bottom` properties (for **vertical alignment**).

**NOTE:** for vertical center alignment, you must declare `display: block; margin: auto;` in addition to `top: 0; bottom: 0;`

To scale your elements more gracefully (with the viewport), you should nest your absolutely positioned element within the relatively positioned parallax element. This will also make the *vertical & horizontal* alignment precise as these values are now *offset relative* to the containing parent element (which is positioned relative).

In other words `absolute` elements are positioned `relative` to its closest/nearest `relative` *containing parent element*.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* So we can see what's happening here */
}

.natecontain { /* This element is now redundant for the purposes of this demonstration and can be removed */
  text-align: center; 
}

.ohwow {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto; /* adjusted for veritcal center alignment */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 1px dashed #868686; /* just so we can see the image better */
    /* center horizontally */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* center vertically */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/1500x1000");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 60%;
  max-height: 60%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <!-- Nest your absolute element within a relative positioned parent element so that the offset properties for left, right, top and bottom are relative to this containing element -->
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Oh Wow (Owen Wilson Voice) Its Nate" title="Look at this doooood." class="ohwow" />
</div>
```